# Visit visa stay allowance

Tags: visas, uk, international-travel, legal

I have 2 year visit visa allowed from feb 2020 to feb 2022. I didnt come in 2020. Now i want to stay from Jan, feb, march and april in uk
Then may in Pakistan, then june, july, august, september and october in uk.

October end back to Pak.

Is this allowed ?

Comment: Yes but want more precise answer in my own situation.

Comment: Its going to be the same answer - you want to stay for 9 months out of 10 calendar months, thats going to be heavily scrutinised for sure.  It definitely looks like an attempt to live in the UK, which you cannot do on a visitor visa - be prepared for a *lot* of questions about how you will be supporting yourself, your ties to your home country etc.  Also be prepared for being refused at the border.